# Display contents of a specific mongoDB document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to display the contents of a collections document in mLab to my web app. Below is the code that I have to get to the subject page. i can get to the subject page with the id of the document appearing in my search bar but nothing comes up. Any feedback will be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
// /route for subjects
router.get('/subject/:id',function (req,res,next) {
    var messages = req.flash('error');
    console.log(classmodule);
    res.render('user/Subject',{title: classmodule.title,description:classmodule.description});
});
```

Here is the code i use in my subject.hbs file

```
{{> header}}

<ul class="breadcrumb">
  <li><a href='profile'>Home</a></li>
  <li><a href='subject'>Subject</a></li>
</ul>
                    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
                    <h3>{{description}}</h3>
{{> footer}}
```

Here is the code I use for my subject.js model,

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

```
//blueprint for each new entry in the db
var schema = new Schema({
    imagePath: {type:String, required: true},
    title: {type:String, required: true},
    uploads:{type:String},
    description:{type:String}

});

module.exports = function classmodule (){
    this.title = title; 
    this.description = description;
};
// export my mongo model to create my product 
module.exports = mongoose.model('Subject', schema);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. You don't ever use the subject model you've created.

Comment: Basically for my app when the user clicks the button to display the subject I am trying to display the title and the description on the web page,(so far nothing comes up). I'm not sure how to do this. i'm nearly certain it has something to do with my route( the first bit of code) I'm new to all this so not too sure what im doing.